Upgrading to Java 8 to Java 17: Issue our project uses wsimport to interact with wsdl api, we already update the dependencies from javax to jakarta
Upgrading to Java 8 to Java 17: Issue our project uses **wsimport **to interact with wsdl api provided by java, we already update the dependencies from javax to jakarta using maven/pom..
Anyone knows or encounter this kind of challenge?
here are some code classes that we are using:
import java.net.URL;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import jakarta.xml.ws.Service;
import jakarta.xml.ws.WebEndpoint;
import jakarta.xml.ws.WebServiceClient;
import jakarta.xml.ws.WebServiceFeature;

import jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import jakarta.xml.ws.handler.HandlerResolver;
import jakarta.xml.ws.spi.Provider;
import jakarta.xml.ws.spi.ServiceDelegate;`

currently using these dependencies for java 17:
**pom.xml
**
<dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.mail</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.mail-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
      <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
      <version>13.0.0</version>
      <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.xml.bind/jakarta.xml.bind-api -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.xml.ws/jakarta.xml.ws-api -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.xml.ws</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.xml.ws-api</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.jws/jakarta.jws-api -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.jws</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.jws-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jaxb/jaxb-runtime -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxws-ri</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.2</version>
      <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>

Expecting to use wsimport or any other alternative library to interact with wsdl api for Java 17.
